# MySQL - Arithmetic across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have two tables, `People` and `Invoices`.

**People**

```
firstname    postcode
Alex         2403
Peter        2357
Michael      3456
```

**Invoices**

```
person       earned
Alex         12300
Alex         3556
Peter        1000
Alex         234
Michael      10000
```

I want to add a column to People called income showing each persons total earnings - how could I implement this?

I believe that the tables should be joined:

```
INNER JOIN Invoices ON People.firstname = Invoices.person
```

But I'm then unsure how to then sum and group the money earned into an income accordingly (I'd assume `COUNT(*)` is used somewhere).

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Comment: @user5226582 I'm aware that these will be necessary to produce the correct result (last paragraph of question) as well as how both work but as I am only learning SQL I'm very hazy on the correct implementation in this instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obviously very flaky relying on 'firstname' and 'person' as a join, as names aren't unique, but assuming you're using an arbitrary data example:

```
select p.firstname, p.postcode, sum(i.earned) earnings from people p
inner join invoices i on p.firstname = i.person
group by i.person
```

gives

```
| *firstname* | *postcode* | *earnings* |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| Alex        | 2403       |   16090    |
| Michael     | 3456       |   10000    |
| Peter       | 2357       |   1000     |
```

Perhaps not the most respectable resource, but this link should help to understand more about using `GROUP BY` with `SUM`

https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php

Comment: Note that the `inner join` will return rows only where both tables have entries.

If you imagine a third person, 'Julie', is present in `people`, but hasn't made any earnings, she wouldn't appear in an `inner join`.  If you want to return ALL `people` and then add any earnings, including null values for any `people` who don't have an entry in `invoices`, you would want to change this to a `left join`.

Answer (score 1):

Since i can't figure it out what your table looks like, i assume that this code would help.

```
SELECT 
    a.firstname, 
    a.postcode, 
    SUM(b.earned)  
FROM 
    People a 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Invoices b 
ON 
    a.firstname = b.person  
GROUP BY 
    a.firstname
```

If you can add more details about your table, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.firstname,sum(p.income)+sum(i.earned) from people p inner join 
invoice i on p.firstname = i.firstname where p.firstname =
'Alex' group by p.firstname;
```

This query must solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, `SUM` should be.

```
SELECT
   firstname, 
   SUM(earned) AS earnings 
FROM People 
INNER JOIN Invoices 
  ON People.firstname = Invoices.person 
GROUP BY person
```

Comment: dont start making new answer. Just update your old answer

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
   firstname, 
   count(earned) AS earnings 
FROM People 
INNER JOIN Invoices 
      ON People.firstname = Invoices.person 
GROUP BY person
```

Comment: This only counts how many entries are present in `invoices` - not the total earnings.  You need to use `sum` instead of `count`